# Working with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I ma trying to adjust my page to screen dimensions. I want to implement media query to get a screen size.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="tabeditor">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.tabeditor {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 768px) {
.tabeditor {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzL084vg/2/)

It shows blue box in both IE and Chrome on either 1920x1080 or 1024x768 resolution.
Seems like I dont understand how it works, Can someone please explain?

Thanks

Comment: It works for me on Chrome & Firefox. Did you notice that you use `max-height` for your media queries? Did you want to write `max-width` instead? Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/bek04x5s/

Comment: You are missing an ending `}` on your `@media` query

Comment: Works fine for me, try zooming in and out on fiddle.

Comment: Screen height != viewport height. Plus, in this jsfiddle view, the result is displayed inside an iframe, so the iframe’s dimensions determine the viewport dimensions. Your query works fine, you are just not testing it under the correct conditions. Try http://jsfiddle.net/bzL084vg/2/embedded/result/ instead – still inside an iframe, but with much less “around”. If your screen is sufficiently high, you should see the result right there already.

Comment: I guess, I need a max-height of a screen resolution then. Is there a media query for that?

Comment: `device-height` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-height. CSS doesn't care about what your monitor size it, it only cares about the output of this particular webpage. JavaScript has some options for more information about the screen size.